# Create a Stacked Column Chart with series in javascript

Tags: javascript, charts

I am trying to create a stacked column chart with 2 categories "**Kosten**" & "**Stromertrag**". Every category has it's own column with different values. Below is the attachment of what I want to achieve.

[image: Stack column chart]

I tried to implement 4-5 chart libraries like canvasjs, highchart, etc. But they want the array of data. But in my case I have below json from which I want to build the same.

```
{
   substratkosten: "9,000"
   kosten1: "156,600"
   kosten2: "298,286"
   kosten3: "64,800"
   strom2: "583,200"
   substrat: "108,000"
}
```

Where first four values is for '**Kosten**' category and last 2 values is for '**Stromertrag**' category.  I also tried to change the chart columns color, but I didn't found any property to achieve the same.

Can anyone please help to achieve the same?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse data in the [format accepted by CanvasJS](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/working-with-data/) and render the chart. Below is the working code.

```js
var jsonData = {
  substratkosten: "9,000",
  kosten1: "156,600",
  kosten2: "298,286",
  kosten3: "64,800",
  strom2: "583,200",
  substrat: "108,000"
};

var data = [];

for (var key in jsonData) {
  if(key.includes("kosten")){
    data.push({type: "stackedColumn", indexLabel: "{y}", dataPoints: [{x: 1, label: "Kosten", y: parseFloat(jsonData[key].replace(/,/g, ''))}]});
  }
  else {
    data.push({type: "stackedColumn", indexLabel: "{y}", dataPoints: [{x: 2, label: "Stromertrag", y: parseFloat(jsonData[key].replace(/,/g, ''))}]})
  }
}

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title:{
    text: "StackedColumn Chart"
  },
  data: data
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine. Checkout this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/ZKucVU9.png

Comment: Here On Hover, Kosten should be Kosten1, And it's above bar on Hover value should be Kosten2